# yocto - How to set permission to command of busybox

Tags: yocto, bitbake, busybox, ownership, yocto-recipe

I am currently working on a yocto projet and I'm looking for a solution to set permission on busybox's command. I have my layer meta-exemple1 in which there is the **recipes-core** that contains **busybox_%.bbappend** and **files/defconfig_patch.cfg** that set configuration's.

I am looking for a way **to set permission** of a specific command for user's..

Example,

Let suppose I have two user, user1 and user2. I want to allow user1 to use to command cat and not the user2

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux there is getfacl and setfacl which you can use to set users permissions on a given binary. More details [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetfacl.htm).

In Yocto, you can use this for example:

```
do_install_append(){
    setfacl -m u:user_name:r-- $D${bindir}/cat
}
```

There are two problems now:

You need to see if busybox packages all the binaries splitted into ${D} or packages one binary "busybox", if it is one binary you can try to append the package of the image recipe.

The idea is to find the recipe that packages your target binary.

The second problem is that Yocto does not keep those permissions when creating the final rootfs, the problem is mentionned [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2016-November/032876.html).

So, you can try the suggested solution which is adding permissions after the package stage with **pkg_postinst_${PN}_append()**, or I suggest that you can create a service that runs on boot and runs setfacl commands on the binaries you want.

This is what I found, hope it helps you finding the right solution.

Comment: Hi, BelhadjSalem, Thanks for your reply. Currently all command in the files /bin , /sbin , /usr/bin and /usr/sbin are linked to /bin/busybox. example : drwxrwxrwc /bin/cat -> /bin/busybox. It may not change acces to command (cat per exemple) due the permission on /bin/busybox ?

Comment: If they are all links to busybox, changing the permission of the link is enough, I think the best workaround is a service at boot that changes the permissions once for all.

Comment: thanks BelhadjSalem. I tried changing permission to symbolic link but it does work .. I have to change permission on the binary /bin/busybox. But I found another way to my probleme. I am using coreutils package. Do you know if there is a way, to add in the coreutils_%.bbappend, the var ALTERNATIE_PRIORITY to all command ? exemple : replacing ALTERNATIE_PRIORITY[bin_x1], ... ALTERNATIE_PRIORITY[bin_xi] by something like ALTERNATIE_PRIORITY[all] ?